# Do I need .fpt and .cdx files to extract data from Foxpro or does the .dbf file contain all the data

Tags: foxpro

I need to transfer a lot of foxpro files over the internet and then import the data into an access database. In some cases the .fpt file is several times bigger than the .dbf file of the same name. From what I have been reading it seems that the .dbf file might hold everything and that I can ignore the .cdx and .fpt files. is this correct

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CDX is a compound index file. From FoxPro help:

> If a table's structural compound index
>   file cannot be located or is deleted
>   or renamed, a dialog box appears when
>   you try to open the table. If you
>   choose the default Cancel push button,
>   the table isn't opened. Choosing
>   Ignore opens the table and removes the
>   flag in the table's header that
>   indicates an associated structural
>   compound index file is present.
>
> Tip   To reassociate a structural
>   compound index that has become
>   dissociated from its table, issue the
>   following command: USE TableName INDEX
>   CDXFileName

If you try to `USE` a table from FoxPro without the CDX file being present you will receive a `Structural CDX file not found` dialog with `Ignore` and `Cancel` buttons.

The .fpt file contains the data from `Memo` type fields. If the dbf has a field of type `Memo` and the .fpt file is missing, FoxPro will not be able to open the dbf. FoxPro will display a message box saying that the memo file is missing or invalid.

From my testing with Access, it didn't seem to affect importing data with the CDX file missing but I couldn't import data without the FPT file.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Dave's answer, yes the .FPT and .CDX files are part of the "table".  Any files marked .TBK can be omitted, these are backup copies of the table.    Also, .FPT and .CDX files are only present when memo fields and table indexes exist, so the absence of either does not necessarily indicate a problem with the table.

Also be prepared for the occasional corrupted table file if this is a regular FTP transfer.